# If $f:[a,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ is finite, then show that $f$ is bounded on $[a,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness, uniform-continuity

> If $f:[a,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ is finite, then show that $f$ is bounded on $[a,\infty)$

I don't know if I am completely right or not.

Help me with this or correct me if find me wrong somewhere.

Let $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ finite, say $l$.

For a given $\epsilon>0$, $\exists$ a real number $b$ such that

$x>b$ $\implies$ $l-\epsilon<f(x)<l+\epsilon$.

Also,Uniform continuity of $f(x)$ implies continuity. Hence, $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b+1]$.

Every continuous function on a closed and bounded interval is bounded $\implies \exists$ a real number say, $m$ such that $|f(x)|<m$ $\forall x \in [a,b+1]$.

Now, let $p =\max\{l-\epsilon , l+\epsilon , m\}$.

Hence, $|f(x)|<p$ $\forall x \in [a,\infty)$.

Comment: Your proof  is correct.

Comment: This looks basically correct but slightly weird that uniform continuity isn't really needed? Is it an exercise?

A note about writing it out though: When you say  "a real number b such that....since, uniform continuity implies continuity", this is all one sentence, but I don't think it's supposed to be. The property you are using is the fact that the limit is l as x tends to infinity. Then in the next sentence you are using continuity. Do see you what I'm getting at?

Comment: Sorry for that
Those two were different things but i didn't use punctuation in between them which create misunderstanding

Comment: Now I have edited that.thanks for your suggestion